# How to have different mock implementations for different test scenarios using the Shallow component Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have created a mockApi which will first return a value 'hasStores: true' in a `__mocks__` folder and calling the mockApi using the useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getNotifications().then((result) => setNotifications(result))
}
```

The first test I am doing does a shallow based off the useEffect returning hasStores: true which is successfully working. I am then trying to create another test by doing a mock and changing the implementation for this to return 'hasStores: false'.

```
const mockApi = require('../../../api/myApi')
jest.spyOn(mockApi, 'getNotifications').mockImplementation(() => {return({hasStores: false })})
```

This is then updating the state of the hasStores to return false but then crashes when it does the shallow. 'TypeError: (0 , _dashboardApi.getNotifications)(...).then is not a function'

```
const dashboardWarning = shallow(<Dashboard />)
```

Comment: I guess it's correct that's it's returning false because you mocked the implementation and asked it to return false always. Second thing I guess you need to mount the component instead of shallow rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not mocking **getNotifications** function correctly. You're providing synchronous implementation which can't be followed by **.then()**. Try instead:

```
jest.spyOn(mockApi, 'getNotifications').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({hasStores: false }))
```

or even better

```
jest.spyOn(mockApi, 'getNotifications').mockResolvedValue({hasStores: false })
```